# x forwarding した firefox@ubuntu14.04 で日本語入力ができない

Tags: windows, ubuntu, x11

Windows7, PuTTY (0.66), Xming (6.9.0.31)

上記の構成で、 ubuntu14.04 から x forwarding しています。ubuntu 14.04 は、 [vagrant の box](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64) を利用していて、日本語対応などが特に行われていない ubuntu です。

この状態で、 x forwarding を行って、 firefox (入力を伴う x11 アプリならなんでもよく、 xterm においても) を起動して、 windows 側で画面を表示させることはできているのですが、この状態から日本語入力を可能にするために、何を行ったらよいのかがわかりません。

質問:
どうやったら、 x forward された画面の上で日本語入力を行えるようになりますか？

Comment: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2127/754 でメタ投稿中の質問です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ibusデーモンを起動すると日本語入力できるようになると思います。
ご参考) http://slavartemp.blogspot.jp/2013/06/xming-teraterm-ssh-lubuntu-x.html